# rinkeby faucet unsupported service error

Tags: ether, rinkeby

I pasted the url of the facebook post and when I selected the amount of ether then this message is shown.[image]

Comment: Try removing `m.` from the beginning of the URL host name.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error using Facebook. I manually tested the URL in browser after logging off Facebook, the post link itself worked; but Rinkeby still didn't accept it. So looked like something wrong with Facebook parser.

I had to set up an account on Twitter. But even that I still got error at beginning. So I trimmed my tweet to fit into two lines. Bingo, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use other faucets, like these:

- https://rinkebyfaucet.com/
- https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby